# Melhor maneira de fazer loop de requisições a uma API PHP

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando com uma api em que envio uma requisição CURL e ela me retorna um json o problema é que se eu colocar em loop no PHP o servidor trava e o processamento é muito lento, uma solução que encontrei foi separa a página que faz a requisição e fazer uma requisição por vez via ajax, porém neste caso após 3 mil vezes o servidor também trava. Preciso de alguma ideia para que consiga efetuar pelo menos 20 mil requisições de forma mais rápida e sem travar o servidor. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Parte do código:

```
public function put($path, $body = null, $params = array()) {
        $body = json_encode($body);
        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body
        );

        $exec = $this->execute($path, $opts, $params);

        return $exec;
    }

while($i<$t){
    $price = $arr_precos[$i];
    $mlb = $arr_ids[$i];
    $i++;

    $edit = '/items/'.$mlb;
    $body = array("price"=>$price);
    $response = $meli->put($edit, $body, $params);
}
```

O código acima executa o loop, a outra maneira que encontrei utilizo o mesmo código porém sem o loop pelo PHP, faço um loop de requisições a um arquivo PHP com esse código via ajax.

Obs. Toda parte de requisição e tratamento de dados e feito em PHP + MYSQL

Comment: Poste o código, assim podemos ter idéias encima de seu contexto.

Comment: Obrigado, editei a pergunta para tentar deixar mais claro

Comment: Ele trava mesmo ou lança uma exceção? Já vi gente com esse problema e na verdade ele chegava no limite de execução. Da uma olhada em set_time_limit.

Comment: Cara, é necessário saber se seu problema é de tempo de execução ou por requisições massivas ao servidor, em seu código, coloque para ele imprimir a cada um segundo, caso não seja time out, o problema é as requisições massivas, você pode colocar um sleep com milésimos de seg para dar um "descanso" ao servidor